# Is there a name for operators that turns $\times$ to $+$ and $/$ to $-$?

Tags: terminology

Just out of curiosity, is there an official names for functions/operator that turns
$\times$ to $+$ and $/$ to $-$?

A few of examples comes to mind

- log
- exp
- argument of a complex number "arg"

Comment: Should the slash be the regular one?

Comment: Also: clockwise rotation through $45^\circ$. :)  (Caution: Font choice may affect angle measure.)

Comment: Well... the logarithm is an example of a homomorphism.

Comment: Likewise is the exponential function (assuming the appropriate domain and codomain).  @Olórin have you taken a course in modern/abstract algebra?

Comment: The logarithm does it; the exponential does not: that goes in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One name for such functions would be “isomorphisms from the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group) of $\ldots$ to the [additive group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_group) of $\ldots$”, where the ellipses stand for whatever objects you're considering – real numbers, complex numbers, matrices, etc. An [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) that respects the structure of a set, in this case the [group structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)). In this context, it would be more natural to talk about preserving inverses rather than mapping division to subtraction; division and subtraction can be described as multiplication by and addition of inverses, respectively.